# Javascript module is variable in function not accessing the outer scope variable

Tags: javascript, module

This is strange... in `function getNumber()` the variable `mostRecent` is not accessing the outer variable `var mostRecent`.

I see in console that console.log(mostRecent) is showing `mostRecent` is updated, but when I do `elements.mostRecent` it still shows the default value.

```
var elements = function () {

    var mostRecent = { "timeStamp" : "0" };
    var timeCollection = [];

    function getElements() {
        var trElements = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (var i = 1; i < trElements.length; ++i) {
            var obj = {
                "action" : trElements[i].children[5].textContent,
                "timeStamp" : trElements[i].children[8].textContent
            }
            timeCollection.push(obj);
        }
    }

    function getNumber() {
        timeCollection.forEach(function findRecent(element) {
            var timeStamp = moment(element["timeStamp"], "MMM. D, YYYY, h:m A");
            var mostRecentMoment = moment(mostRecent["timeStamp"], "MMM. D, YYYY, h:m A");
            if (moment(timeStamp).isAfter(mostRecentMoment)) { mostRecent = element; }
        });

        console.log(mostRecent);
    }

    function refresh() {
        getElements();
        getNumber();
    }

    return {
        mostRecent : mostRecent,
        refresh: refresh
    }
}();

elements.refresh();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
var foo = { bar: 1, baz: 2 };
var tar = foo;
foo = { poo: 3, par: 4 };

tar
// <- { bar: 1, baz: 2 }
```

Effectively losing the reference.

You could do:

```
var foo = { bar: 1, baz: 2 };
var thing = {
    get tar () { return foo; }
};
foo = { poo: 3, par: 4 };

thing.tar;
// <- { poo: 3, par: 4 }
```

Using getters can complicate your code, though. You may prefer to simply keep the reference "a level above".

```
var thing = {
    foo: { bar: 1, baz: 2 }
};
// just return thing
thing.foo = { poo: 3, par: 4 };

// as long as you use the reference to thing, foo will always be up to date
thing.foo;
// <- { poo: 3, par: 4 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The property `mostRecent` will not automatically update when the internal variable `mostRecent` changes. Make it a function instead to get the latest version of the internal variable:

```
return {
    getMostRecent: function () { 
        return mostRecent; 
    },
    refresh: refresh
};
```

Comment: Originally, in return { mostRecent : mostRecent }, was the { mostRecent : a variable holding a copy of the var mostRecent contents rather than a reference to the memory location?